# Prevent applet from caching downloaded files

Tags: java, caching

I have an applet that retrieves files for printing from the network, and I occasionally have a problem with it returning a cached version of the file instead of the actual if it has changed.

For example:

```
URL http = new URL(url +"/"+ m_printfile.get(i));
Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(http, myFormat, das);
DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
job.print(myDoc, aset);
```

Since I'm using SimpleDoc to print the file, I haven't found a way to use the URLConnection object, which is the only way I've seen to disable caching a file.

Is there a way to do it with the URL object, or is there a way I can pass the URLConnection to SimpleDoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can pass `URLConnection` to `SimpleDoc` like this:

```
URL http = new URL(url +"/"+ m_printfile.get(i));
URLConnection conn = http.openConnection();
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.connect();
Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(conn.getInputStream(), myFormat, das);
DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
job.print(myDoc, aset);
```

**2)** Dirty way to avoid caching is to add a random-irrelevant data like this:

```
URL http = new URL(url +"/"+ m_printfile.get(i) +"?z="+Math.random() );
```

such, each time it's looks like different URL, so the cache not impact...

**P.S.** Your second line seems to me wierd.. (`Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(http, myFormat, das)`). it's really works for you? i mean, `http` is not an `InputStream` object.. am i wrong?

Comment: Your comment at the end lead me down the right path to figuring it out. The myFormat var was set like so: myFormat = DocFlavor.URL.*** which allows you to pass in a URL object. Changing to your code broke it until I realized I needed to update it to: myFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.***